# Read (or download) a CSV from URL without knowing the full name using Python

Tags: python, csv, download, export

I would like to read (or download, see below) a .csv from an URL without knowing it's full name using Python.
URL only has a list of .csv files, a single file is added every day with the time of the upload in the name of the file, which changes every day, format is: Data_Feed_20230525_1234_EST.csv

My code returns the following error

`IndexError: list index out of range`

```
import pandas as pd
from glob2 import glob
date = "20230525"
file = glob("https://internalurl.net/Data/Data_Feed_" + date + "_*_EST.csv") [0]
data = pd.read_csv(file, header=0, skip_blank_lines=False)
print(data)
```

If I use the full path without `glob`, it works

```
file = "https://internalurl.net/Data/Data_Feed_20230525_1234_EST.csv"
```

If I download the file via browser and run the above code for my Downloads folder, it also works as expected

```
file = glob("C:/Users/sb92/Downloads/Data_Feed_" + date + "_*_EST.csv") [0]
```

So alternatively if there is a way to Download the file from the URL without knowing the full name, that would also help... I tried `requests` function, but was not able to add glob in there.

Comment: Try putting the URL but without the last part (filename) into your browser. Do you see file tree, or something else?

Comment: Yes, does bring up the list of the files

Comment: then you should be able to obtain list of files with `requests` module. Try simple `r = requests.get("[URL]")` and then printout `r.text`. If you can see the file there simply parse them to list of strings.
Idk if `glob` can help you, as it's used to browse local files.

If `requests` lib fails, try ftplib https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html

Comment: When trying the above `requests` I'm getting `HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found`. Is this have to do with the internal URL that I'm trying to access?